# Checking symbols in string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I am doing a problem on coderbyte and the problem is as follows:

> Using the JavaScript language, have the function `SimpleSymbols(str)`
>   take the `str` parameter being passed and determine if it is an
>   acceptable sequence by either returning the string `true` or `false`. The
>   `str` parameter will be composed of `+` and `=` symbols with several letters
>   between them (ie. `++d+===+c++==a`) and for the string to be `true` each
>   letter must be surrounded by a `+` symbol. So the string to the left
>   would be `false`. The string will not be empty and will have at least
>   one letter.

The code that I have written is this:

```
var SimpleSymbols = function(str){
    var alpha = /[A-Za-z]/;
    var symbolarr = str.split("");
    for(var i = 0; i < symbolarr.length; i++) {
        if(alpha.test(symbolarr[i])) { 
            if(symbolarr[i-1] != "+" & symbolarr[i+1] != "+") {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }   
    return true;
}
```

The problem is that when I test the case `SimpleSymbols("+a=")` I am getting `true` I have read through my code a few times and can't debug this. Can anyone spot the error?

Comment: I see several, you're using the binary AND instead of the logical, you're not doing a bounds check to make sure symbolarr[i+1] exists, your formatting should be cluing you that your loop is not closed properly, etc.

Comment: at least the quick fix here is replace `&` with `||` (or logical). The first character should not be a letter, so you can check the first letter and bypass or return false... The same rule is applied to the last character.

Comment: I see. You know sometimes I hold back on doing this kind of thing because I think that my code will be long, but I fail to realize that performance and readability is much more important than the length of my code. Right?

Comment: I would choose either depending on the requirement. Such as when the performance is not really needed, we can choose a short and easy to understand code. If the performance is strictly required, we normally have to use a long code, this may not be always true but it's often. The long code may be also more complex in logic, so many comments should be added for later reference.

Comment: @KingKing is it valid to use i-1 and i+1 in a for loop ? isnt the loop already iterating variables in squence ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek `i-1` and `i+1` here mean the previous and the next index of the current index `i`. There is just 1 loop here. There is no reason for it to be invalid.

Comment: @KingKing i mean does JS already store values before iterating array ? i mean using i-1 and i+1 is like sending pointer to future and to past does this affect performance ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek I don't think there is any special effect on performance here. The pointer (or variable) is just the `i`, while `i-1` and `i+1` are just normal expressions calculated from `i`, these expressions are evaluated in each loop (no cache).

Comment: @KingKing is not pointer position stored in memory ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek only the `i` is stored, and its value is increased by 1 every loop. Of course the immediate result of expressions may be stored somewhere. But looks like this is more related to assembly than a high-level language.

Comment: Unless you're iterating through a bajillion items I fail to see why any of this matters, you're still looking at ten million + ops per second.

Comment: @ProllyGeek you may want to do some performance test, here is a good online tool http://jsperf.com/ (I'm not very interested in picking out even the tiniest difference in performance but looks like you're very excited with it :)

Comment: @KingKing believe it or not , but i tested many cases and using incremented pointer is always faster !! http://jsperf.com/js-pointers3

Comment: @KingKing while using a past pointer position is slower !http://jsperf.com/js-pointers4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Tweaking your solution

Replace `&` with `&&`, they mean very different things.

Minor comment: you don't need to split the string into an array to access its characters; you can access them directly with `str[i]`.

Ignore the commenter who said you need a range check: `arr[-1]` will just return `undefined`, which will not be equal to `+` as you would expect.

#### Regexp solution

Test for the presence of a regexp giving the invalid sequence. If it's there, the string is illegal.

```
function SimpleSymbols(str) {
    return !/([^+]|^)[A-Za-z]([^+]|$)/).test(str);
}
```

In English:

```
Test for the presence of the following regexp:
    Find any character other than +, or the beginning of the string
    followed by a letter
    followed by any character other than +, or the end of the string
If it is present, return false, else true
```

#### State machine approach

A useful way to think about writing such programs is as a state machine. We will use three states: `start` for the beginning, `have_plus` when we have just seen a plus sign, and `need_plus` when we need a plus sign following a letter.

```
function SimpleSymbols(str) {
    var state = "start";
    var alpha = /[A-Za-z]/;

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var type = alpha.test(str[i]) ? 'letter' : str[i] === '+' ? 'plus' : 'other';

        switch (state) {
            case "start":
                switch (type) {
                    case 'letter':                      return false;
                    case 'plus'    state = "have_plus"; break;
                    case 'other':                       break; 
                }
                break;
            case "need_plus":
                switch (type) {
                    case 'letter':                      return false;
                    case 'plus':   state = "have_plus"; break;
                    case 'other':                       return false;
                }
                break;
            case "have_plus":
                switch (type) {
                    case 'letter': state = "need_plus"; break;
                    case 'plus':                        break;
                    case 'other':  state = "start";     break;
                }
                break;
        }

    }
    if (state === "need_plus") return false;
    return true;
}
```

It's a little longer, but it might be more readable and more maintainable. But we can do better. We will  encapsulate the state logic in a data structure as follows:

```
var transitions = {
    start:     {letter: "fail",      plus: "have_plus",   other: "start"},
    need_plus: {letter: "fail",      plus: "have_plus",   other: "fail"},
    have_plus: {letter: "need_plus", plus: "have_plus",   other: "start"},
    fail:      {letter: "fail",      plus: "fail",        other: "fail"}
};
```

Now our program just runs through the state machine:

```
function SimpleSymbols(str) {
    var state = "start",
        alpha = /[A-Za-z]/;

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var type = alpha.test(str[i]) ? 'letter' : str[i] === '+' ? 'plus' : 'other';
        state = transitions[state][type];
    }
    return state != "fail";
}
```

We could bundle this up into a state-machine object:

```
function stateMachine(state, transitions) {
    return {
        go: function(type) { state = transitions[state][type]; }
        state: function() { return state; }
    };
}
```

Now we can write `SimpleSymbols' as

```
function SimpleSymbols(str) {
    var machine = stateMachine("start", transitions),
        alpha = /[A-Za-z]/;

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var type = alpha.test(str[i]) ? 'letter' : str[i] === '+' ? 'plus' : 'other';
        machine.go(type);
    }
    return machine.state() != "fail";
}
```

It would be good practice to disentangle the classification of tokens from the logic for running the machine:

```
function token_type(c) {
    return /A-Za-z]/.test(str[i]) ? 'letter' : str[i] === '+' ? 'plus' : 'other';
}
```

Then just

```
function SimpleSymbols(str) {
    var machine = stateMachine("start", transitions);
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) { machine.go(token_type(str[i])); }
    return machine.state() != "fail";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the minor comment. Taught me something new for sure!